# Where to put a user-editable database connection string for a Scala Lift web application?

Tags: scala, lift

I need to be able to configure a Scala Lift web application of mine with such things like a database connection string. Where should I best put such a data (I use Jetty for hosting) and how to access it from the application code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a [properties file](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Properties) in `src/main/resources/props/` and may then access the data using, for example, `Props.get("db.url")`.

Comment: But how do I change the properties on the production server as the war package is built and deployed there?

Comment: You add this file before building the war package and it will automatically be included. As the help file says, you may use different files for different servers or modes.

Comment: As far as I understand, these props files are built into a war file, once and forever. But I want a user (a server administrator) to be able to specify any (really any - I can't know a database server address, user name and password in advance) value without rebuilding the application every time.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood you. I am not sure there is a pre-defined external location for property files. You might have to specify one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [Data Source in Jetty](http://www.google.no/search?q=jetty+datasource) and connect to it like this:

```
val dataSource = (new InitialContext).lookup(name).asInstanceOf[DataSource]
val conn = dataSource.getConnection
```

where `name` is the name JNDI name of the data source, e.g. "java:jdbc/MyDB".

I don't know how you'd interface this to Lift, though, as I haven't used Lift.